# Strtok in C++ giving me unexpected behavior

Tags: c++

I've got this function:

```
void simple_shell::parse_command(char* cmd, char** cmdTokens) {
  // TODO: tokenize the command string into arguments
  char *token = strtok(cmd, " ");
  int count = 0;

  while (token != NULL) {
      count = count + 1;
      cout << token << endl;
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }

  char *secondToken = strtok(cmd, " ");
  *cmdTokens = new char[count];
  count = 0;

  while (secondToken != NULL) {
      cmdTokens[count] = secondToken;
      cout << secondToken << endl;
      secondToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
      count = count + 1;
  }
}
```

I am basically taking cmd and splitting it with the space as a delimiter. Then, in the while loop, I am printing each token.

It works fine with the first while loop and the first token. If the string is "hello world", then I get "hello" and "world" on two separate lines, which is exactly what I want.

However, in the second loop, something goes wrong and I only get "hello", and nothing else. What is going on here?

Comment: Don't use `strtok()` to split strings in c++. It's error prone and unreliable regarding reentrance. Here are some better approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/most-elegant-way-to-split-a-string . Also stop using `char*` and `new` when using c++.

Comment: You are aware, of course, that `strtok()` ***modifies*** its buffer parameter. That's how it works. Read its description. So, on the first pass through the string, the `char` buffer gets utterly destroyed, and nuked by `strtok()`. The shown code naively expects `cmd` to be its original pristine self, on the second pass. Unfortunately, that's not going to happen. Better luck next time.

Comment: *I am basically taking cmd and splitting it with the space as a delimiter.* -- Funny, [I'm doing the same thing](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/727f7740e1c5c73f).  Compare that code to your attempt with `strtok`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtok()` operates on a null-terminated string as input, but it *modifies* the string as it goes.  When it finds a delimiter in the string, it injects a nul character where the delimiter is located and returns a pointer to the token that is in front of the injected nul.  On the next call with a NULL input pointer, the search starts after the previously injected nul.

So, when you run through your first loop, everything is output correctly, but `strtok()` has altered the contents of `cmd` to replace all of the space characters with nul characters.  So, when you run your second loop, it can't find any space characters in `cmd` anymore, and stops looking when the nul character after the first token is reached, even though it is not really the last nul in the string.

So, you have a few choices.

You could duplicate `cmd` on each loop. You will also have to duplicate each token that you store in the output array, since they will be pointing at temporary memory:

```
int simple_shell::parse_command(char* cmd, char*** cmdTokens)
{
    *cmdTokens = NULL;

    char *dup = strdup(cmd);
    if (!dup)
        return -1;

    int count = 0;

    char *token = strtok(dup, " ");
    while (token)
    {
        ++count;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    free(dup);

    try {
        *cmdTokens = new char*[count];
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        dup = strdup(cmd);
        if (!dup)
        {
            delete[] *cmdTokens;
            return -1;
        }

        token = strtok(dup, " ");
        count = 0;

        while (token)
        {
            cmdTokens[count] = strdup(token);
            if (!cmdTokens[count])
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    free(cmdTokens[i]);
                delete[] *cmdTokens;
                return -1;
            }

            ++count;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

```
char** tokens;
int numTokens = shell.parse_command("hello world", &tokens);
if (numTokens != -1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << tokens[i] << std::endl;
        free(tokens[i]);
    }
    delete[] tokens;
}
```

Or, you could stop using `strtok()` and use a less destructive way to extract substrings.  You will still have to duplicate the individual tokens, though, since there won't be any nul characters injected into `cmd` anymore:

```
const char* nextToken(const char *str)
{
    if (!str)
        return NULL;

    while (*str == ' ')
        ++str;

    if (*str == '\0')
        return NULL;

    return str;
}

const char* endOfToken(const char *str)
{
    if (!str)
        return NULL;

    while ((*str != ' ') && (*str != '\0'))
        ++str;

    return ptr;
}

int simple_shell::parse_command(char* cmd, char*** cmdTokens)
{
    *cmdTokens = NULL;

    char *ptr = cmd;
    int count = 0;

    const char *token = nextToken(ptr);
    while (token)
    {
        ++count;
        token = nextToken(endOfToken(token));
    }

    try {
        *cmdTokens = new char*[count];
    }
    catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        ptr = cmd;
        count = 0;

        token = nextToken(ptr);
        while (token)
        {
            const char *end = endOfToken(token);
            int len = (end-token);

            try {
                cmdTokens[count] = new char[len+1];
            }
            catch (const std::bad_alloc&) {
                for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                    delete[] cmdTokens[i];
                return -1;
            }

            memcpy(cmdTokens[count], token, len);
            cmdTokens[count][len] = '\0';
            ++count;

            token = nextToken(end);
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

```
char** tokens;
int numTokens = shell.parse_command("hello world", &tokens);
if (numTokens != -1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << tokens[i] << std::endl;
        delete[] tokens[i];
    }
    delete[] tokens;
}
```

Or, if you don't like duplicating the tokens, just return pointers to them, as well as their lengths:

```
struct token_info
{
    char* token;
    int length;
}

const char* nextToken(const char *str)
{
    if (!str)
        return NULL;

    while (*str == ' ')
        ++str;

    if (*str == '\0')
        return NULL;

    return str;
}

const char* endOfToken(const char *str)
{
    if (!str)
        return NULL;

    while ((*str != ' ') && (*str != '\0'))
        ++str;

    return ptr;
}

int simple_shell::parse_command(char* cmd, token_info** cmdTokens)
{
    *cmdTokens = NULL;

    char *ptr = cmd;
    int count = 0;

    const char *token = nextToken(ptr);
    while (token)
    {
        ++count;
        token = nextToken(endOfToken(token));
    }

    try {
        *cmdTokens = new token_info[count];
    }
    catch (const std:bad_alloc&) {
        return -1;
    }

    if (count > 0)
    {
        ptr = cmd;
        count = 0;

        token = nextToken(ptr);
        while (token)
        {
            const char *end = endOfToken(token);

            cmdTokens[count].token = const_cast<char*>(token);
            cmdTokens[count].length = (end-token);
            ++count;

            token = nextToken(end);
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

```
token_info* tokens;
int numTokens = shell.parse_command("hello world", &tokens);
if (numTokens != -1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numTokens; ++i)
        std::cout << std::string(tokens[i].token, tokens[i].length) << std::endl;
    delete[] tokens;
}
```

But, since you are clearly using C++, you should stop using such archaic C-style methods, and use more modern C++ practices instead, eg:

```
std::vector<std::string> simple_shell::parse_command(const std::string &cmd)
{
    std::istringstream iss(cmd);
    return std::vector<std::string>(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
    );
}
```

```
std::vector<std::string> tokens = shell.parse_command("hello world");
for (auto &token: tokens)
    std::cout << token << std::endl;
```

Comment: Any suggestions on how I can get the output I need?

Comment: Use `strdup(cmd)` before each loop and then tokenize the duplicated string, or else don't use `strtok()` at all.  There are other ways to tokenize a string without altering it.

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations Drop `strtok()` and use something more stable.

Comment: @Remy _"Use `strdup(cmd)` before each loop "_ I smell memory leaks :P

Comment: @user0042: sure, but that is what happens when you use C-style memory management.  Prefer C++ RAII instead, so memory is managed automatically.

Comment: @Remy I'd aggressively recommend to drop `strtok()` in favor of the various available c++ solutions (as you did in your edited answer now).